# CUSTOM ERROR HTML PAGE IS NOT REDIRECTING WHENEVER 403 ERROR IS ENCOUNTERED

Tags: php

I have created an `.htaccess` file in my web-based application where i have written the ErrorDocument redirection code lyk below

```
ErrorDocument 403 /errornopage.html
```

But it's not working. My `Apache` version is - `2.2.17` and `PHP` version is- `5.3.5`. But when i try to redirect to a .php page or a .html page whenever 404 error is encountered itz working lyk below-

```
ErrorDocument 404 /errornopage.php
```

or

```
ErrorDocument 404 /errornopage.html
```

For 403 error code,whether you try to redirect to a `.html` page or `.php` page, both are not working. Please Help.

Comment: How you are handling 404 error ?Can you share your code?

Comment: yeah sure. In my. htacess file (C:\wamp\www\project\.htacess) , i have written this particular code -  ErrorDocument 404 http://[IPADDRESS]/project/errornopage.html

Comment: and the above line of code is working fine

Comment: badly need help from someone

Comment: Try with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11877340/how-to-handle-a-403-error-with-php

Comment: This will definitely help you. http://serverfault.com/questions/331833/custom-403-error-page-not-showing

Comment: ok thanks Bikash for the help...let me try it out

Answer (score 0):

there is difference between 403 and 404
Use This code In htaccess file for 403 :
Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 403 http://localhost/ht/403.html

You can change the (http://localhost/ht/403.html) to whatever

For 404 error

Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/ht/404.html