# How to handle 403 error in file_get_contents()?

Tags: php, error-handling

I'm getting 403 errors when using `file_get_contents()`,

I want to handle this error like this,

```
if(required_function(file_get_contents($url))){  //detects there is a 403
    error
// do some special set of tasks
}else{
    //run normally
}
```

I tried to read the error since the url shows the error when I pasted in the browser , but is not getting in to `file_get_contents()` so I failed. I don't think changing user agent will work because systems may still be able to detect this is a script ,so I realized if I could detect the 403 error, the script will not crash.

any ideas ?

please help , I'm new to programming. thanks a lot.

Comment: I believe you have a typo in required_function u forgot an n

Comment: corrected , that's the function I need from you guys :) if possible

Comment: Oh ok i personally never handled a 403... But i know that you can handle 404 from .htaccess have it redirect to a custom page... Maybe try that ?

Comment: Take a look at this. It is exactly what i thought u handle it throught the .htaccess file. There is no function http://stackoverflow.com/a/11877381/7428715

Comment: Just need to get data from a url , if the url gives 403 error , the script should do something else to prevent it from crashing :)

Comment: U can do ErrorDocument 403/linktothepageyouwanttoredirecttowhena403happens

Comment: Make a new file in your root directory named .htaccess just that extension no filename

Comment: And put it in it the answer i linked you to should help you understand how it works

Comment: I will try that too :) thanks @redsecurity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally I'm suggesting you to use cURL instead of file_get_contents. file_get_contents is great for basic content oriented GET requests. But the header, HTTP request method, timeout, redirects, and other important things do not matter for it.

Nevertheless, to detect status code (403, 200, 500 etc.) you can use *get_headers()* call or *$http_response_header* auto-assigned variable.

*$http_response_header* is a predefined variable and it is updated on each *file_get_contents* call.

Following code may give you status code (403, 200 etc) directly.

```
preg_match( "#HTTP/[0-9\.]+\s+([0-9]+)#", $http_response_header[0], $match);
$statusCode = intval($match[1]);
```

For more information and content of variable please check official documentation

[$http_response_header  — HTTP response headers](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php)

[get_headers — Fetches all the headers sent by the server in response to a HTTP request](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php)

(Better Alternative) [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

> **Warning about** $http_response_header, *[(from php.net)](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php#113361)*
>
> Note that the HTTP wrapper has a hard
>   limit of 1024 characters for the header lines. Any HTTP header received that is longer than this will be ignored and won't appear in $http_response_header. The cURL extension doesn't have this limit.

Comment: I agree with this answer try this first

Comment: if(get_headers($url)[0] =="HTTP/1.1 403 FORBIDDEN") will work right ?

Comment: Yes, the example you gave should work. Also I edited my answer and added an example which gives statusCode of request directly. You may want to use it. Additionally, if you think this solution is correct and explanatory, mark it as correct answer.

Comment: yeah , I just tried your code , it only gives 0 @TuğcaEker

Comment: Let me to check it again.

Comment: You're welcome. Also please consider the warning on answer which is provided by Nicolas Toniazzi at php.net. *(In your case it won't be problem but you may encounter this problem in future.)*

Answer (score 3):

I just encountered similar problem and resolved it. My solution covers much more cases:

Q: How to do POST in PHP, not using cURL?

A: Use file_get_contents().

Q: How to make file_get_contents() not to complain with error HTTP status?

A: Set ingore_errors=>TRUE in options passed to file_get_contents().

Q: How to retrieve http status in response?

A: After file_get_contents() call, evaluate $http_response_header

Q: How to retrieve response body even for an error http response code?

A: Set ignore_errors=>TRUE and file_get_contents() will return body.

Here is the code example:

```
$reqBody = '{"description":"test"}';
$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => "Content-Type: application/json\r\n",
        'ignore_errors' => TRUE,
        'content' => $reqBody
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$url = 'http://mysite';
// with ignore_errors=true, file_get_contents() won't complain
$respBody = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

// evaluate the response header, the way you want.
// In particular it contains http status code for response
var_dump($http_response_header);

// with ignore_errors=true, you get respBody even for bad http response code
echo $respBody;
```