# If statement with file get contents to avoid 403 error

Tags: javascript, php, html, file-get-contents, http-status-code-403

i am trying to get string of cross domain but sometime or some website gives a `403 Forbidden` error. So to protect from getting error i am trying to include `if statement`, if site one get error while getting string then it will move to else part and take string from site two.

Error :

> Warning: file_get_contents(https://www.example.com): Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden

Code :

```
$siteone = file_get_contents("https://www.example.com");
$sitetwo = file_get_contents("https://www.example.net");

if ($siteone === false) {
      $error = error_get_last();
      echo $sitetwo;
} else {
      echo $siteone;
}
```

So, here if `example.com` give `403 error` then it automatically ignore `example.com` and get string from `example.net`.

I have also tried `try` and `catch` but it didn't work. Please help!!

Comment: You could use `get_headers` to test for a `200` response

Comment: `get_headers` with `array` or `if statement`?. can you please write some example code

Comment: Hope this answers your questions https://stackoverflow.com/a/41802322/2324206

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to handle 403 error in file\_get\_contents()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41802082/how-to-handle-403-error-in-file-get-contents)

Comment: @DarkKnight trying same but still no success :(

Comment: Check site two only if the first one fails or you'll be forbidden in second one soon too.

Comment: @Robert `http_response($siteone,'403');` ??

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using `file_get_contents` or getting caught up writing functions using `get_headers` etc to verify response code before attempting to capture the contents I'd suggest using cURL. Within your curl request you can inspect the HTTP Response code directly and the added advantage is that you automatically have the content available to you if the request is successful.

```
$errors = $valid = $content = array();
$break_on_success = false;

$urls=array(
    'https://www.bogus.com',
    'https://stackoverflow.com/',
    'https://developer.mozilla.org',
    'https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/admin',
    'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70518330/if-statement-with-file-get-contents-to-avoid-403-error',
    'https://www.gumtree.com/',
    'https://httpstat.us/307',
    'https://httpstat.us/403',
    'https://httpstat.us/401',
    'https://www.farcebook.com'
);


foreach( $urls as $url ){
    
    $ch=curl_init( $url );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2 );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $cacert );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CAPATH, $cacert );
    $response=curl_exec( $ch );
    
    
    if( !curl_errno( $ch ) ){
        
        $status=curl_getinfo( $ch, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE );
        
        if( $status==200 ){
        
            $valid[]=$url;
            $content[ $url ]=$response;
            
            if( $break_on_success )break;
            
        }else{
            $errors[ $status ]=$url;
        }
    }
    $ch=null;
}

printf('<pre>%s</pre>',print_r($valid,true));
printf('<pre>%s</pre>',print_r($errors,true));
```

This will generate the following output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => https://stackoverflow.com/
    [1] => https://developer.mozilla.org
    [2] => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70518330/if-statement-with-file-get-contents-to-avoid-403-error
    [3] => https://www.gumtree.com/
    [4] => https://httpstat.us/307
    [5] => https://www.farcebook.com
)
Array
(
    [404] => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/admin
    [403] => https://httpstat.us/403
    [401] => https://httpstat.us/401
)
```

The urls listed in the first array have been processed and do not return a bogus http status code whereas those in the second can be ignored. If, in the above, you set `$break_on_success=true;` the code would halt once the first url to return a good response has been found. The HTML content for each url is stored within the `$content` array and can be subsequently processed.

I mentioned using `get_headers` to accomplish this goal. Whilst it is possible there are several pitfalls that one might encounter and any code might end up becoming more complicated than is necessary.