# Apache Virtual Host configuration to serve static files from S3 bucket

Tags: apache, amazon-s3

I need to implement the following logic for my apache virtual host:

- If file exists in S3 bucket, serve it from there
- Otherwise send request to a fastcgi service (php-fpm in this particular use case)

It's not acceptable to serve S3 files through php and we can't map s3 bucket as folder for apache.

So, the question is: If there is a known way to check if file exists (if not it's 403/404 error) in S3 bucket from a virtual-host configuration and implement logic based on this?

Comment: I don't think Apache can do this - you'll need some code.  You don't need to use PHP to serve the file per se - generate a signed URL and redirect the user to that new URL.

Comment: If you use s3 static website hosting, then it's definitely possible to use `proxy_pass` to get those resources from s3. As for logic around 403/404, I'm sure there are ways, but man, this is getting tricky...

Answer (score 0):

You say you want to:

- If file exists in S3 bucket, serve it from there
- Otherwise send request to a fastcgi service (php-fpm in this particular use case)

While I could imagine it might be more convenient to be able to fully configure this in Apache, I suggest this might work better:

- Always send request to a fastcgi service (php-fpmIf)
- Have the service check if the file exists in S3
- If file exists, service returns the S3 file (or redirects to file).
- Else the service processes the request and generates the result

Amazon provides an SDK for to access S3 using PHP:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/service-s3.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RetrieveObjSingleOpPHP.html

For the approach you were asking for, there's an answered SO question how to handle a 403 error in PHP:

[how to handle a 403 error with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11877340/how-to-handle-a-403-error-with-php)